# Performance issue on 19c

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

Recently we have updated our database from 11g to 19c.

While testing the application in new database version, we have encountered an performance issue for a particular view, which is working absolutely fine, but causing performance issue in 19c.

While analysis the plan, we have seen there is a massive change in execution plan that's leads to very very poor performance of the view in 19c.

Surprisingly, others views are working fine.

It will be nice, if you can put some light on this issue.

Thanks with Regards,
JD

Comment: Can you share the details of the explain plan in 11g vs. 19c?

Comment: There are *many* things can go wrong with performance when upgrading from 11g to 19c.  If you only have one specific performance problem then you're doing pretty well.  Oracle introduces new performance tricks with each release, but there's also a small chance of them backfiring.  Post both execution plans here and we may be able to dig deeper.  (Make sure you generate them with `explain plan for ...` and `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display)`, which will display text version that are easier to compare, and contain more information than most graphical explain plans.)

Answer (score 2):

If only one thing went wrong during an upgrade, I'd consider that a huge success. Skip the in-depth performance analysis and simply "cheat" by asking Oracle to execute that one query the same way it did before. Modify the slow query or view to use the hint `OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE`. For example:

```
select /*+ optimizer_features_enable('11.2.0.4') */ * from all_tables;
```

That's the only *specific* advice I have for this situation. If that doesn't work, then you need to go down the typical performance troubleshooting path (get the execution plan with actual numbers, look at the slow operations and wrong cardinalities, check statistics, etc.) But that would probably need to be a separate question with much more details.

Answer (score -2):

There is so simple Answer ,
I would suggest you can start with this note in MOS.

Things to Consider to Avoid Database Performance Problems on 19c (Doc ID 2773012.1)